# Is there a way to choose between sets of characters in regex?

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

Is there a way to match only mat and mis like this?

I've tried it in a regex tester and it doesn't work. Why not? Does square brackets only take a single character?

```regex
m[(?:is)(?:at)]
```

Comment: You probably wanted to write it as `\bm(?:is|at)\b` and yes, you're correct in assumption that square brackets represent a character set with whatever inside as allowed charset and one charset represents only one character.

Answer (score 0):

The sqare brackets define character sets.

`\d` for example is a shorthand for the `[0123456789]`

if you want to have alternatives you have to use `|`, like `this|that` that matches either word.

if the alternatives are a sub pattern you can group them with normal parenthesis.

`like (this|that)`  matches `'like this'` and `'like that'`

So to match `'mis'` and `'mat'` it can be:

```
mis|mat
```

or if you want the common prefix

```
m(is|at)
```

and if you do not want the capture

```
m(?:is|at)
```

(but in this case you can use the first suggestion that is better readable)